# NextJS Server Component update Client component when data changes

Tags: mongodb, next.js, changestream

I'm using NextJS 14.0.3 with MongoDB Change Streams and need to update a client component when a change is detected in the database. When I change something on my database, it detects the change, but doesn't update the component. I assume it's because I'm not using useState, but that's not support on server components.

This is what I have on my page.tsx

```
import Logs from "./components/Logs";
import GetLogs from "@/actions/GetLogs";
import Log from "@/models/log.model";
import { connectDatabase } from "@/lib/db";
import LogTable from "./components/LogTable";

connectDatabase();

export default async function Logs() {
    let logs: any[] = await GetLogs();

    Log.watch().on("change", (change: any) => {
        switch (change.operationType) {
            case "insert":
                logs = [change.fullDocument, ...logs];
                break;
            case "update":
                logs = logs((log) =>
                    log._id === change.documentKey._id
                        ? change.fullDocument
                        : log
                );
                break;
            case "delete":
                logs = logs.filter(
                    (log) => log._id !== change.documentKey._id
                );
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });

    return (
        <section className="flex flex-col gap-4 w-full">
            <LogTable logs={logs} />
        </section>
    );
}
```

I tried using a client component with a useState and passed it into a server component, but Nextjs doesn't like that.